# Application.js file not in scope

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-events

Anyone ever have this issue - I am not able to call any JS from any page within my Rails app that is located in my application js file. I can execute code in an external file OR embedded in the page but not I'm that file. I'm stumped. Any ideas. I'm trying to access jQwery btw.

Here's my application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.jeditable" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://use.typekit.com/jdj1xqp.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Here's the output

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.jeditable.js?1306352056" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://use.typekit.com/jdj1xqp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1305685037" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1305685037" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1305685037" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1305685037" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1305685037" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1307485399" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here's my application.js

```
    // Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
    // This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
    $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#big-search-box").bind("keyup", function() {
         $("#big-search-box").addClass("loading"); // show the spinner
         var form = $("#live-search-form"); // grab the form wrapping the search bar.
         var url = "/schools/find"; // live_search action.  
         var formData = form.serialize(); // grab the data in the form  
         $.get(url, formData, function(html) { // perform an AJAX get
           $("#big-search-box").removeClass("loading"); // hide the spinner
           $("#live-search-results").html(html); // replace the "results" div with the         results
         });
      });
   });
```

Comment: Is the file being loaded correctly? Check out the Network panel in the Chrome developer tools or the Net panel in Firebug. You should see a 200 success code and the contents of your `application.js` file.

Comment: Could you update your question to include a few code examples of what you're trying to invoke, how you're trying to invoke it, and where that code exists? Also, where/how are you including application.js in your page? This information should be helpful in answering your question. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, do you have `= javascript_include_tag :defaults` in your `app/views/layouts/application.*` ? if not, you need to manually include `application.js`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple problem, you are loading jquery:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" %>
```

and prototype:

```
<script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1305685037" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These are going to butt heads badly. You need to call [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Then you need to change any jquery code to use `jQuery.` rather than `$.`

OR, you need to remove anything that uses prototype, which is every default rails js file.

Your application.js should be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#big-search-box").bind("keyup", function() {
        jQuery("#big-search-box").addClass("loading"); // show the spinner
        var form = jQuery("#live-search-form"); // grab the form wrapping the search bar.
        var url = "/schools/find"; // live_search action.  
        var formData = form.serialize(); // grab the data in the form  
        jQuery.get(url, formData, function(html) { // perform an AJAX get
            jQuery("#big-search-box").removeClass("loading"); // hide the spinner
            jQuery("#live-search-results").html(html); // replace the "results" div with the         results
        });
    });
});
```

There is a jQuery shortcut to re-alias the `$`, but this is a clearer approach.